# Javascript Redirection stops working on deployment server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am working on website it works great on my local iis server but when i deployed my website on server my code

```
function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
}
function onLoad() {
        if (getCookie("QCuserName") == "") {
            window.location = "Login.aspx";
        }
        else {
            if (getCookie("QCreturnURl") == "") {
               document.getElementById("cookiecheck").style.visibility = "visible";
            } else {
               window.location = getCookie("QCreturnURl");
            }
        }
}
```

This line `window.location` did not execute until i don't put break point on that line. Seriously i am not getting this. For the time being i solved this thing by `setTimeout(function () { window.location = getCookie("QCreturnURl") }, 800);` but i don't know the reason how my problem is solved. And what is the logical reason behind that???

Comment: Maybe javascript can't perform a redirect if the page isn't yet fully loaded? (just a thought). Is it possible to perform this logic server side perhaps. Or use window.location.href ?

Comment: Don't know this thing is totally confusing

Comment: add some console.log statements and see if there's anything suspicious.